# Part to use for solar charging terminal

Tags: arduino, switches

I would like to use an arduino device to control a 12V 17W water pump and filter, what type of part to I need that can switch the 12V power on and off?

Comment: Types of parts that may be useful for you: a relay, or a bipolar junction transistor operating as a switch, or a MOSFET operating as a switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only 3.3 or 5V logic high to switch on a 12Vdc motor, You may want to consider short circuit overload, thermal overload and inductive turn off effects. The better FETs with low Ron resistance usually require a bigger gate voltage to perform this. There are some chips which generate this internally using a voltage pump (MOS charge pump cct) to generate this higher internal gate voltage.

**Conclusion** 
I recommend the **[TPS2204](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva092/slva092.pdf)**  chip, capable of 2A sustained in an 8 pin DIP package.

Additional precautions are given [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva092/slva092.pdf) and buy [here](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TPS2034P/296-12236-5-ND/413528) for $2 /1pc or $1 /1kpc
[image]

You can put an Alum.elect. cap. (>=16V) on the output to suppress commutation noise and use twisted pair wire. This driver can handle large capacitance and surge currents.